# _mm_srli_si128 equivalent on altivec

Tags: c, simd, sse, powerpc, altivec

I am porting a program written in SSE 4.2 to Altivec. I have a problem in finding the equivalent for the intrinsic `_mm_srli_si128`.

When I googled I found `vec_slo` as the equivalent.

Here is my sample program for shifting the contents by 1 byte left:

```
void test(void *buf, void *buf1)
{
    vector unsigned int x;
    vector unsigned int a;

    x = vec_ld(0, (vector unsigned int *)buf);
    a = vec_ld(0, (vector unsigned int *)buf1);

    vec_slo(x, a);
}

int main()
{
    char buf[17]="1111111111111111";
    char buf1[17]="0000000000000001";

    test(buf, buf1);
}
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
line 20.1: 1506-930 (S) The function "vec_slo" is not a type-generic macro.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument for `vec_slo` needs to be `vector signed char` or `vector unsigned char`. So change:

```
vector unsigned int a;
```

to:

```
vector unsigned char a;
```

and change:

```
a = vec_ld(0, (vector unsigned int *)buf1);
```

to:

```
a = vec_ld(0, (vector unsigned char *)buf1);
```

There are a couple of other problems with your code which you'll see when you get it compile and run:

- `buf` and `buf1` need to be 16 byte aligned
- the value for the shift in `buf1` needs to be a 4 bit literal integer shifted left by 3 bits, not a character

Here is a simplified/corrected version of your example code - it's written for gcc so may need minor changes for whatever compiler you are using (xlc ?):

```
int main(void)
{
    vector unsigned char v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    vector unsigned char vshift = vec_splat_u8(1 << 3);   // shift left by 1 byte
    vector unsigned char vshifted = vec_slo(v, vshift);

    printf("v        = %vu\n", v);
    printf("vshift   = %vu\n", vshift);
    printf("vshifted = %vu\n", vshifted);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How the value of buf1 should be?

Comment: Hi Paul, Is there any document, which will help me in getting more insight into the altivec inrinsics.

Comment: @sunmoon: yes, you want the [Motorola "AltiVec Programming Interface Manual" ALTIVECPIM/D](http://www.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/ALTIVECPIM.pdf).

Comment: Hi Paul, Do you have any tutorial with example programs?

Comment: @sunmoon: you could start with the IBM developer pages, e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/power/library/pa-unrollav2/

Comment: You might also find this Apple document useful: http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/Accelerate_sse_migration/Accelerate_sse_migration.pdf - it maps SSE instructions to AltiVec instructions.

Comment: Hi Paul, vec_splat_u8(1 << 3);  -- How did this achieve the shift left by 1 byte. Can you please give some info on this.

Comment: @sunmoon: the constant shift is encoded in bits 3..6 of vshift (bits 1..4 using IBM convention). So if you want a shift of `n` bytes then the `vshift` value will be `n << 3`. Check the AltiVec manual I linked to above for details of this instruction/intrinsic.